# (GEE) The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, sentinel-2

How do I solve this error

[image: Screenshot of code and error]

```
// Compute Normalized Difference Vegetation Index over S2-L2 product.

//Step 1: Access the Sentinel-2 Level-2A data and filter it for all the the images of the year 2020 that lie within the geometries boundaries. Keep only the relevant bands and filter for cloud coverage.
var s2a = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-07-31')
                  .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));

//Print your ImageCollection to your console tab to inspect it
print(s2a, 'Image Collection  July 2020');
Map.centerObject(s2a,9)

//Step 2: Create a single Image by reducing by Median and clip it to the extent of the geometry
var s2a_median = s2a.median()
                    .clip(geometry);

//Print your Image to your console tab to inspect it
print(s2a_median, 'Median reduced Image  July 2020');

//Add your Image as a map layer
var visParams = {'min': 400,'max': [4000,3000,3000],   'bands':'B8,B4,B3'};
Map.addLayer(s2a_median, visParams, 'S2  July 2020 Median');

//Step 3: Calculate the NDVI
var ndvi_3 = s2a_median.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
                      .rename('NDVI');



// Plot a time series of NDVI at a single location.
Map.centerObject(geometry, 1);
Map.addLayer(ndvi_3,
  {bands: 'NDVI', min: 0.1, max: 0.9, palette: ['white', 'green']},
  'NDVI Mosaic');
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'yellow'}, 'geometry');
var l8Chart = ui.Chart.image.series(ndvi_3.select('NDVI'), geometry)
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
   title: 'Sentinel-2 NDVI Time Series at ROI',
   trendlines: {
     0: {color: 'CC0000'}
   },
   lineWidth: 1,
   pointSize: 3,
  });
print(l8Chart);


//You can also create more complex colour palettes via hex strings.
//this color combination is taken from the Examples script Image -> Normalized Difference:
var palette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];
//Please keep in mind that for this palette, you should set your minimum visible value to 0, as it s designed for this purpose.
//This is due to it being a gradient from brown to green tones, with a heavy focus on the green side. If we would set min: -1, NDVI = 0 would already be displayed in a dark green tone.
//You can recognize this by checking the palette-section of your layer information for ndvi_3.

// Display the input image and the NDVI derived from it.
Map.addLayer(ndvi_3, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: palette}, 'NDVI  July 2020 V3')
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are trying to create an NDVI time series of July month from S2 images having less than 10 percent cloud cover. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I just discovered what went wrong. I created a single image by aggregating into a median and you cannot create timeseries of a single frame ofcourse.

Comment: You can post the solution as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In step 2 I am creating a single image (median) and because of this it is impossible to create a timeseries afterwards.